Unable to call rest api from Background Service in ionic 5
In android mobile app developed in Ionic 5 Cordava, we want to call some rest api when mobile screen is off, but not any one api is called during that time, we want to call that api every 5 seconds.
We have added below code in App.components

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
      console.log('checking visibilychange:', document.visibilityState);
      if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        console.log('App is in the background');
        console.log('In Background');
        // this.backgroundMode.setEnabled(true);

        console.log('this.login == true', this.login == true);

        this.bluetoothService.backgroundMode = true;
        this.startBackgroundTask();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.startBackgroundTask();


        }, 5000);
});```

  startBackgroundTask() {
      this.apiCallInProgress = false;


      // this.backgroundMode.enable();
      console.log('this.backgroundMode.enable()', this.backgroundMode.isEnabled);

      console.log('!this.apiCallInProgress', this.apiCallInProgress);

      
      if (!this.apiCallInProgress) {

        this.apiCallInProgress = true;
        this.startBackgroundGeolocation();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.apiCallInProgress = false;
        }, 5000);
      }
     
    
    }



api is not called during this time. I am not sure whether I am missing anything
